# NCURSES - colors in pad

Tags: c, ncurses

I am writing an application in ncurses and I am dealing with colour displaying in pads. I add some text into pad `p` with colour attribute on like this:

```
    if(has_colors())
        start_color();
    init_pair(0, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(0));
    while( (ch=fgetc(f)) != EOF){
            waddch(p,ch);
    }
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(0));
    fclose(f);
```

But then when I display part of the tab with `prefresh(p,0, 0, 0,0, LINES-1,COLS-1);` the text is printed without any change. (only the background is a bit different because I started colour mode). I am afraid that when the text is copied from the pad to screen, it does not copy the formatting, is that right? If so, is there any way how to accomplish that?

Thanks!

|||-----EDIT------|||
So even when I cahnge the key to something different than zero, it doesn't work. I am printing into the pad with this:

```
    init_pair(3,COLOR_RED,COLOR_CYAN);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));
    for (i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        waddch(p,str[i]);
    }
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
```

and the text after `prefresh` is displayed as normal.

Comment: That's actually two questions, and since there is no complete test program, there's nothing left to answer.

Comment: I don't see, why is this two question. But I have made it work anyway, so you are right there is nothing left to answer. I will paste the solution and close the question.

Comment: I'm writing a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Color pair 0 is special, because (referring to the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html)) it is always the default foreground and background colors:

> Color  pair  0 is assumed to be white on black, but is
>   actually whatever the terminal implements before color
>   is initialized.  It cannot be modified by the application.

There are three components of color pairs which combine to form a cell's color (see [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-Color-Rendering)):

- background character
- window attribute set via wattron, etc.
- video attributes (including COLOR_PAIR value) passed in the parameter to waddch.

The last two affect the result if a nonzero color-pair is passed; otherwise they do not (and the preceding item on the list is used).  These are all *window* operations.  The functions attron/attron apply to `stdscr`, not to the pad or window `p`.  If those were changed to `wattron(p,COLOR_PAIR(3));`, etc., the result would be improved.

Comment: Even if I change the key of the pair to something different than 0, it has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

this excerpt from the man pages for ncurses indicates the problem is using color pair 0.

### The init_pair routine changes the definition of a color-pair. It takes three arguments: the number of the color-pair to be changed, the foreground color number, and the background color number. For portable applications:

The value of the first argument must be between **1 and COLOR_PAIRS-1**, except that if default colors are used (see use_default_colors) the upper limit is adjusted to allow for extra pairs which use a default color in foreground and/or background. "  emphasis mine

Comment: Again, I have tried to change the number of the key, nothing has changed. Please see the edit.

Comment: suggest refreshing the pad 'prefresh(); after changing the contents of the pad

Comment: I think... before defining init_color(3...) that the entries for 1 and 2 need to be defined

Comment: this is one way to include the color attributes to a char:   ' waddch( p, str[i] | COLOR_PAIR(3) )'

Comment: you might want to use the 'touchwin()' function after the attron() function (and again after the attoff() function to update the pad attributes

Comment: Yay, ' waddch( p, str[i] | COLOR_PAIR(3) )'  made it and now everything is displayed properly :). Post it as answer and I will tag it as solution.Thanks.